# How to add signature key to a keras model

Tags: keras

I am building a tensorflow keras model which has to be converted to tensorflowlite and run in Kotlin. The model runs fine in Anaconda Spyder. But when I try to convert this model to tensorflow lite, I am getting error.

```
class OneStep(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, model, chars_from_ids, ids_from_chars, temperature=1.0):
    super().__init__()
    self.temperature = temperature
    self.model = model
    self.chars_from_ids = chars_from_ids
    self.ids_from_chars = ids_from_chars

    # Create a mask to prevent "[UNK]" from being generated.
    skip_ids = self.ids_from_chars(['[UNK]'])[:, None]
    sparse_mask = tf.SparseTensor(
        # Put a -inf at each bad index.
        values=[-float('inf')]*len(skip_ids),
        indices=skip_ids,
        # Match the shape to the vocabulary
        dense_shape=[len(ids_from_chars.get_vocabulary())])
    self.prediction_mask = tf.sparse.to_dense(sparse_mask)

  @tf.function
  def generate_one_step(self, inputs, states=None):
    # Convert strings to token IDs.
    input_chars = tf.strings.unicode_split(inputs, 'UTF-8')
    input_ids = self.ids_from_chars(input_chars).to_tensor()

    # Run the model.
    # predicted_logits.shape is [batch, char, next_char_logits]
    predicted_logits, states = self.model(inputs=input_ids, states=states,
                                          return_state=True)
    # Only use the last prediction.
    predicted_logits = predicted_logits[:, -1, :]
    predicted_logits = predicted_logits/self.temperature
    # Apply the prediction mask: prevent "[UNK]" from being generated.
    predicted_logits = predicted_logits + self.prediction_mask

    # Sample the output logits to generate token IDs.
    predicted_ids = tf.random.categorical(predicted_logits, num_samples=1)
    predicted_ids = tf.squeeze(predicted_ids, axis=-1)

    # Convert from token ids to characters
    predicted_chars = self.chars_from_ids(predicted_ids)

    # Return the characters and model state.
    return predicted_chars, states

one_step_model = OneStep(model, chars_from_ids, ids_from_chars)

tf.saved_model.save(one_step_model, 'one_step')
```

I tried to convert this model to tensorflowlite in this code extract. I tried to convert the model in Anaconda Spyder, but it is expecting atleast one signeture key. I am not sure how to save the model in the first place with a signature key.

```
one_step_reloaded = tf.saved_model.load('one_step')
#print(one_step_reloaded.SignatureDefEntry)

# Convert the model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('one_step') # path to the SavedModel directory
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('Bible.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)


 raise ValueError("Only support at least one signature key.")

ValueError: Only support at least one signature key.
```

Can you help how to add signature key to this model before saving it so that it can be converted to tensorflowlite?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am getting exactly the same error. I am trying to convert a `saved_model` (which I did not develop) to `tflite`

Comment: Google asked me to email the model and I did. Looks like they are working on this model. In the mean time, what I learned is TFLite only supports few models as of data and definitely not deep learning networks. Hopefully, they will extend the support for them soon

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with a Keras model, you can directly convert from that format to TensorFlow Lite using the `TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model` API. As an example:

```
# Convert the model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

Comment: I am getting a new error now. I am using tensorflow 2.7.0 
  File "C:\Users\kumar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py", line 1118, in _freeze_keras_model
    if not isinstance(self._keras_model.call, _def_function.Function):

AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'call'